# Fragment swipe view-pager -- android

Tags: android, performance

I draw the pie graph in android, i have two different fragment which i can swipe using view pager. I used paint concept to draw the pie chart in my application. When i use the Fragment view pager, the activity loads the pie diagram for several times. Is it possible to load the view pager for once a while or at the time of swipe. I have onDraw method to draw the pie chart, when i swipe or touch the screen it calls for several time. I tied

> setOffscreenPageLimit

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pie_Chart, container,
                false);
        lv1 = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linear);
        drawpieGraph();
        return view;
    }
```

But no use of it. Can anyone guide me on this topic. Thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you draw the graph? Show us some code.

Comment: I have edited my question, from onCreateView, i call the drawGraph method which contains the paint.

Comment: i think at that time view is not attached better to call at the time of onCreate() method in Fragment may be this will works for u or call at the time of onActivityAttached()

Comment: Thanks, but if i create the onCreate method, then how come i can import the layout in that. Can you please guide me in-depth.